# multiple matches in QRegularExpression global pattern

Tags: regex, qt

I have to parse a tsv string coming from a serial bus.

To identify the string from other data it has a *header* composed by `#!`.

An example of this string is:

```
#!  0.01    0.02    10.5
```

I would like to match the float numbers form this string, but the number of them is unknown.

For the moment I'm working with global regex with this pattern

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

it works but it does not check the *header*.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: `if (line.startsWith(QLatin1String("#!"))) { /* build and use the regex */ }` ?

Comment: Does QT support look behind in regex? If so, that is what you need. You may also use non capturing groups.

Comment: QRegularExpression supports look behinds. Still that's pointless for a global matching round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **peppe** said in comments, you can check that a line starts with your marker and then use a regexp to capture numbers:

```
if (line.startsWith(QLatin1String("#!")))
{
    QRegExp re("([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)");

    QStringList list;
    int pos = 0;

    while ((pos = re.indexIn(line, pos)) != -1)
    {
        double value = re.cap(1).toDouble();
        qDebug() << value;

        pos += re.matchedLength();
    }
}
```

Another approach is to check the entire line and then split it by unnecessary parts:

```
QRegExp re("^#!(\\s+[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\s*)+$");
if (re.indexIn(line) != -1)
{
    QStringList list = line.split(QRegExp("[^0-9\\.]");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i
    {
        double value = list.at(i).toDouble();
        qDebug() << value;
    }
}
```